# What happened to Xamarin.Forms.Markup with XF 5.0?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Markup;

namespace Templates
{
    public partial class ABC : Grid
    {
        public ABC()
        {
            var SVG = new SvgCachedImage()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            }
            .Bind(SvgCachedImage.SourceProperty, nameof(IconSource), source: this);
```

In 4.8 I was able to do this:

```
.Bind(SvgCachedImage.SourceProperty, nameof(IconSource), source: this);
```

But now in 5.0 pre 4 it's telling me that Xamarin.Forms.Markup no longer exists and .Bind no longer works.

Does anyone know if there's a solution for this in 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lately c# Markup for Xamarin.Forms has been moved to [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup), thus you need to:

- Install that package in your project.
- Reference that package in your class using `using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup` (also remove the old `using Xamarin.Forms.Markup;`)

Comment: I've checked and it seems like even after adding the latest version of the Toolkit the .Bind isn't available any more. Any ideas?

Comment: The markup overall is working but .Bind is not?

Comment: .Bind doesn't exist as far as I can see as part of the toolkit.  No extension method Bind

Comment: It is working with me, which version are you using just to confirm pre5?

Comment: Yes I am using the pre5 version and it's giving me a message saying there's no .Bind extension.

Comment: This is weird can you clean/rebuild your solution?

Comment: I will open another more specific question for this

Answer (score 1):

if you read the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0-pre4#additional-fixes-included-in-this-release) you'll see

- "Remove markup extensions" ([#12730](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/12730))

and the linked Github issue says

> Markup extensions are being moved to the Xamarin Community Toolkit

Comment: I've checked and it seems like even after adding the latest version of the Toolkit the .Bind isn't available any more.  Any ideas?